# Read file, check correctness of column, write file C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file-io, delimiter

I need to check certain columns of data to make sure there are no trailing blank spaces. At first thought I thought it would be very easy, but after attempting to achieve the goal I have got stuck.

I know that there should be 6-digits in the column I need to check. If there is less I will reject, if there are more I will trim the blank spaces. After doing that for the entire file, I want to write it back to the file with the same delimiters.

This is my attempt:

Everything seems to be working correctly except for writing the file.

```
if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
                {
                    string lines = sr.ReadLine();
                    string[] delimit = lines.Split('|');

                    while (delimit[count] != "COLUMN_DATA_TO_CHANGE")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }

                    string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@filename);

                    foreach(string nextLine in allLines.Skip(1)){
                        string[] tempLine = nextLine.Split('|');
                        if (tempLine[count].Length == 6)
                        {
                            checkColumn(tempLine);
                            writeFile(tempLine);
                        }
                        else if (tempLine[count].Length > 6)
                        {
                            tempLine[count] = tempLine[count].Trim();
                            checkColumn(tempLine);                               
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Not enough numbers");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 

 public static void checkColumn(string[] str)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str[count].Length; i++)
        {
            char[] c = str[count].ToCharArray();
            if (!Char.IsDigit(c[i]))
            {
                throw new Exception("A non-digit is contained in data");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void writeFile(string[] str)
    {
        string temp;
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename+ "_tmp", false))
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            bool firstColumn = true;

            foreach (string value in str)
            {
                if (!firstColumn)
                {
                    builder.Append('|');
                }
                if (value.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '"', ',' }) != -1)
                {
                    builder.AppendFormat("\"{0}\"", value.Replace("\"", "\"\""));
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.Append(value);
                }
                firstColumn = false;
            }
            temp = builder.ToString();
            sw.WriteLine(temp);
        }
    }
```

If there is a better way to go about this, I would love to hear it. Thank you for looking at the question.

edit:
file structure-

country| firstname| lastname| uniqueID (column I am checking)| address| etc

USA|John|Doe|123456 |5 main street|

notice the blank space after the 6

Comment: you could create a class that mimics the structure of the file.. then you can read all text in a single function call.. then from there you can create a List<YourClass> and hold the data that way and once finished you can save all the data back in a delimited format to the same file.. also can you show an example of a single line of what the file structure looks like

Comment: @MethodMan added an edit to the question

Comment: how long is your file?  Ideally if you could control the .trim() on the id when the file is created that'd be the best solution.  Otherwise reading the entire file in, trimming, and then writing it back would be the second easiest way to go.

Comment: The file length can vary depending on who is uploading the file. My test file is 66 rows long, but others could be several thousand

Comment: @AlexanderMatusiak Unfortunately I will not have access to the files as they are created. They are uploaded to our servers for us to then handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var oldLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath):
var newLines = oldLines.Select(FixLine).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, newLines);

string FixLine(string oldLine)
{
    string fixedLine = ....
    return fixedLine;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with writing the file is that you're opening the output file for each output line, and you're opening it with append=false, which causes the file to be overwritten every time. A better approach would be to open the output file one time (probably right after validating the input file header).

Another problem is that you're opening the input file a second time with .ReadAllLines(). It would be better to read the existing file one line at a time in a loop.

Consider this modification:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename+ "_tmp", false))
{
    string nextLine;

    while ((nextLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] tempLine = nextLine.Split('|');
        ...
        writeFile(sw, tempLine);
```